# Serve three.js?

Tags: node.js, socket.io, three.js, webgl

I'm trying to serve the example found [here](http://threejs.org/examples/canvas_geometry_panorama.html) over a [Node] http server with socket.io.

The example runs just fine.

The code below...

```
var app = require('http').createServer(handler)
  , io = require('socket.io').listen(app)
  , fs = require('fs')

app.listen(8086);

function handler (req, res) {
  fs.readFile(__dirname + '/spinnycube.html',
  function (err, data) {
    if (err) {
      res.writeHead(500);
      return res.end('Error loading spinnycube.html');
    }

    res.writeHead(200);
    res.end(data);
  });
}

io.sockets.on('connection', function (socket) {
  socket.emit('news', { hello: 'world' });
  socket.on('my other event', function (data) {
    console.log(data);
  });
});
```

...is what I'm using to serve the page, index.html.  I've chosen port 8086 because it is unused; it makes no difference between this and any other port number.

The example runs fine by itself, and any index.html served this way runs great, except when I add in three.js code and try to serve the example (as index.html).  Everything gets served and operates normally *except* the 3D scene.

What is it about serving three.js code this way that makes it break down?  Why is it that everything works except that?

Any help is *greatly* appreciated.  Thank you.

Note: Even though [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12510375/httpserver-in-node-js-to-serve-three-js) question is similar, the answer does say anything about why WebGL (via three.js) will not render when being served as explained above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried to serve the example page. You have to change some links in the page for it to work. Like change

```
<script src="../build/three.min.js"></script>
```

to

```
<script src="http://threejs.org/build/three.min.js"></script>
```

And

```
loadTexture( 'textures/cube/skybox/px.jpg' ), // right
...
loadTexture( 'textures/cube/skybox/nz.jpg' )  // front
```

to

```
loadTexture( 'http://threejs.org/examples/textures/cube/skybox/px.jpg' ), // right
...
loadTexture( 'http://threejs.org/examples/textures/cube/skybox/nz.jpg' )  // front
```

The page loads perfectly and three.js code also works.
I don't understand how socket.io comes into picture. So maybe, it is causing problems.

Comment: Thanks for the response.  I went in and did all of that, it seems fine using just node's http server; so yes, socket.io would appear to be causing problems.  Its inclusion in this case is for later dynamically modifying the 3D scene over sockets.